# highly public communication breakdown

Tags: word-meaning

Does "breakdown" mean "failure (to stick up to the promise - for example, promise the vaccine efficacy is 85%, yet actually  the efficacy is only 75%)"?

> In the tumultuous rollout of AstraZeneca's COVID-19 vaccine, all eyes were on the United States this week, where the company had a [highly public communication breakdown](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/03/astrazeneca-lowers-efficacy-claim-covid-19-vaccine-bit-after-boards-rebuke) over the vaccine's efficacy with an expert panel overseeing a large study in the Americas. But on the other side of the Atlantic, the vaccine faces new concerns about safety as an explanation gains ground for the unusual strokes and clotting disorders recorded in at least 30 recipients.

> Source:  [Science](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/03/rare-clotting-disorder-may-cloud-worlds-hopes-astrazenecas-covid-19-vaccine)

Comment: A 'communication breakdown' is a failure to communicate a  message properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a breakdown (in this context) is a failure, and a "communication breakdowns" is when the communication is incomprehensible or absent to the other party.

I do not believe that this is exactly what they were trying to say int the article, as AZ did communicate effectively.  However, the issue appears to be what they communicated.  But, as usual, news articles are often horribly written.